# FIXED Accidentally deleted all users and forgotten root password. How can I use my computer again?

Tags: root, user-profile

**The problem is now fixed by completely resetting the computer and reinstalling Windows. Here is the old question though:**

I wanted to delete just one user, but the window didn't react to my mouse so I clicked the button again. Now there's no user left, and I forgot the password for root (when I select 'root' from the recovery menu, it's asking me to enter the password). I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

What can I do to add a new admin account and use my computer again? I did some research, but no solution I found completely fits in my situation.

And: it isn't a duplicate! In that other question, Ubuntu didn't ask for a root password. But here it does!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/101890

Comment: That is totally weird. It says *"[root] password:"*? If it is like that, the method will be in the Black Hat Hacker terrain...

Comment: When exactly is it asking for the root password? The recovery should not ask for the root password. Take a photo of it or something, and upload it.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, it did. Now the problem is gone though.

Comment: @Alaa Well, it asked for it, yes. I'm sorry that I didn't mark this problem as fixed.